# android.content.activitynotfoundexception

Tags: android, video-streaming, wifi, video-recording

I had made a videorecording app for my android project on eclipse on the windows xp platform...at 1st it wud just recors a video with no audio i/o...as soon as i seemed to have added the audiorecording feature, the process would just close just like that...i used the ddms and found the following log frm my device....

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:Unable to find activity class("namespace of the project)

can any1 please help me with this????

PS:I'd also like to appreciate your help if in case u could tel me how to facilitate real-time duplex video-streaming over WIFI.....

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `Activity` to your `Androidmanifest.xml`?  Have you changed the name of your `Activity` without updating the manifest?

Comment: i have added the Activity into the manifest....i added the camer permissions also into the manifest....i did'nt change the name of the activity but just added the audio-recording features into the  code along with the earlier video-recording ones...

Comment: how many `Activities` do you have?  make sure the entry in the manifest is spelt the same as the class name.

Comment: there is only one activity there and i have nt changed the name or the working of this activity....and there are 3 java files in my app...1st file initializes the hardware, 2nd records the video and the 3rd file plays the recorded file..